# How can I print the std output from Python script using Java runtime?

Tags: java, python, jsp, runtime, ioexception

I want to print the std ouput of the following Python script using Java Runtime. My ideal result would simply print out "Hello World". Why am I getting `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start`? My Path and Python environment variables are properly configured.

```
String commandline = "python /c start python C:\\Users\\Name\\HelloWorld.py"

try {
                //TODO java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir"
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandline);
                process.waitFor();

                // Store command line output
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                String result = builder.toString();

                if (result != null) {
                    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                    out.println("<div>" + result + "</div>");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    PrintWriter out = null;
                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                e1.printStackTrace(out);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                e2.printStackTrace(out);
            }
```

Comment: You could do this... buy why?  Why not emulate the python scripts functionality into java or vice versa?   I'll add an answer, but no matter what, it won't be portable, and it won't be as good as a native solution in either java or python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to change your python output to output to a file.   I believe that you can do this somewhat simply by changing the process string to:

```
String commandline = "python /c start python C:\\Users\\Name\\HelloWorld.py > output.txt"
```

Then use any of the million ways that java has to open / read files to handle the file, which should contain the output from your python program.  You may want to add a thread.sleep(1000) since your python script won't be running in the JVM and may need time to complete, since the instructions in your java program are synchronous.